# Google Analytics get tracker by trackingId

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I currently have this code, to try and find the right tracker I need (among 8-12 trackers):

```
ga.getAll().forEach(function(tracker) {
    if(tracker.get('trackingId') === "UA-62921111-4") {
```

Instead of getting every tracker and iterating through them, is there an easy way to do something like `ga.getTracker("UA-62921111-4")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `ga.getTracker` on analytics.js. it only has `ga.getByName` and `ga.getAll`.

for your reference you can check this. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers

So to achieve what you need i have written the following code which should be added to your file after the analytics.js has been loaded:

```
(function(){
    trackers = {}
    ga.getAll().forEach(function(tracker) {
        trackers[tracker.get('trackingId')]=tracker;
    });
    ga.getTracker=function(id){
        if(trackers[id])
        return trackers[id];
    };
})();
```

this basically fetches all the trackers once and stores them in an object and it defines the missing `ga.getTracker`.

so now you can call `ga.getTracker("UA-62921111-4")` function to get your tracker.

Comment: `ga.getTracker=function(id){return trackers[id]}` (so without the if) would end up doing the same thing

Comment: Also, note that there can be more than one tracker with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a good one-liner:

```
var tracker = ga.getAll().filter(tracker => (tracker.get('trackingId') === 'UA-62925944-4'))[0]
```

But note that if you have multiple trackers, `ga` might seem ready before the tracker you want has loaded. I was wanting to get data from the tracker for form fields, so I inserted those fields on submit, to make sure everything had loaded.